# Windows Server 2003 SP3: "the specified network name is no longer available"

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

I have a network, where the Active Directory Domain Controllers run Windows Server 2019.

We have an old SharePoint server running Windows Server 2003 SP2 running as a virtual machine on an old Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V server.

We recently had to rebuild our domain controller. That used to run Windows Server 2012R2, but now everything got upgraded to Windows Server 2019 except the old Hyper-V box and the old SharePoint virtual machine.

I added the Hyper-V server to the domain with no issues. I was able to make the old SharePoint server as a Workgroup computer, however when I try adding that to the new domain controller, I receive the error message:

```
The specified network name is no longer available
```

Upon entering the domain name and clicking the OK button, I receive the dialog box requesting my system admin domain credentials. I successfully enter the credentials, the login dialog box disappears but in its place comes a message box that states that the network  name is no longer available.

I did try changing the computer name prior to joining the domain to something new. Although that should not be a factor, I covered my bases. That had no effect.

Thoughts?

Comment: May be due to SMB1 is now disabled by default. Wouldn't recommended it, but that may be it. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

Comment: @GregAskew I saw that link, but I did not have SMB1 as an entry, so I ignored it. I added that entry now and tried both a 0 and a 1 with reboots and same problem.

Comment: Run the following command `sc config srv start=auto` reboot, check the following services are running Browser service , Workstation,  Server and try again.

Comment: @jfrmilner The command repeatedly yields "NOTE The option name includes the equal sign."

Comment: Maybe it needs a space after the equals `sc config srv start= auto`. Failing that set the Server service to Automatic using `services.msc` and be sure it and the Computer Browser and Workstation services are running before retrying.

Comment: @jfrmilner The space did not help. All 3 services are set to automatic and all 3 of them are started. Sorry, the problem lies elsewhere, unfortunately.